# Why does Xcode tell me that the last case will never be executed?

Tags: xcode, swift, switch-statement

For another question here on StackOverflow, I was typing some testing code in Swift, and to my surprise it told me that the last case would never be executed (the one with `.B, .C, .D`), anyone have any ideas?

```
func test(someEnum: EnumType) {
    switch someEnum {
    case .A:
        someMethodSpecificToA()
        fallthrough
    case .B, .C, .D:
        someMethodSpecificToTheseThreeLetters()
        fallthrough
    case .E:
        someMethodSpecificToE()
        fallthrough
    case .A, .E:
        aMethodIShouldCallOnVowels()
    case .B, .C, .D:
        aMethodIShouldCallOnAllConsonants()
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like I completely misunderstood `fallthrough` :o

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fallthrough` keyword means "go down to the next case without performing any additional checking. Your code will execute these four methods when `.A` is encountered:

```
    someMethodSpecificToA()
    someMethodSpecificToTheseThreeLetters()
    someMethodSpecificToE()
    aMethodIShouldCallOnVowels()
```

because it would enter on `case .A`, and keep "falling through" all the way to `aMethodIShouldCallOnVowels()`.

Since there is no `fallthrough` on `.A` and `.E`, once the first instance of `.B .C .D` case is reached on the `switch`, it would go on all the way to `.A .E`. At this point there's no additional switching going on, and `.B .C .D` has already been explored through the initial jump.

That is why your approach is not going to work: you need to split your `switch` into two individual ones, or to add a special case for `.E` and `.A`.

```
switch someEnum {
case .A .E:
    switch someEnum {
    case .A:
        someMethodSpecificToA()
    case .E:     
        someMethodSpecificToE()
    }
    aMethodIShouldCallOnVowels()
case .B, .C, .D:
    someMethodSpecificToTheseThreeLetters()
    aMethodIShouldCallOnAllConsonants()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't fall trough from `case .A, .E` and last case is the same as second case, so it will be matched to the second one.

Comment: Is there a way to have control flow to the next case statement, and having it check it, and possibly bind values? `continue` can't be used.

Comment: No, I'm not aware of such construct in Swift. I think you should refactor your switch as @dasblinkenlight proposed

Answer (score 0):

In simpler terms, you can't repeat a case. In your code snippet `case .B, .C, .D:` is repeated. A case will also fail to execute if you do this `case .B, .C, .C` by mistake too.